# How to update underlying ViewModel property when deleting a Photo using an Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, edit

My situation is this:

I have this `ViewModel:`

```
public class RealtyViewModel
{
     public RealtyViewModel()
     {
          Realty = new Realty();
          Photos = new Collection<File>();
     }

     public Realty Realty { get; set; }

     public Collection<File> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

I pass this `RealtyViewModel` to my `Edit.cshtml` view. Inside the Edit view I call a `Photos.cshtml` partial view. The Photos partial view also uses the same `@model RealtyViewModel`.

Now, inside the `Photos.cshtml` partial view I do an AJAX request to delete a photo:

```
@Ajax.ImageActionLink
(@Url.Content(Model.Photos[i].Path), @Localization.Delete, "640", "480",
"DeletePhoto", new {realtyId = Model.Realty.Id, photoId = Model.Photos[i].Id},
new AjaxOptions()
                 {
                      Confirm = @Localization.DeleteConfirmation,
                      HttpMethod = HttpVerbs.Post.ToString(),
                      OnComplete = string.Format("deletePhotoFromPage('{0}')",
                                                                  Model.Photos[i].Id),
                      OnSuccess = "LoadCycle",
                      UpdateTargetId = "myDiv",
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

                 }, new {data_photoId = Model.Photos[i].Id})
```

I run this code:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeletePhoto(string realtyId, string photoId)
{
    Realty realty = DocumentSession.Load<Realty>(realtyId);

    realty.Photos.Remove(photoId);

    File photo = DocumentSession.Load<File>(photoId);

    // Deletes the file in the database
    DocumentSession.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.Delete(photoId, null);

    // Deletes the file in the disk
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(photo.Path));

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

The problem is: my current `realtyViewModel` that I passed to the Edit view still references the photos I have deleted using the AJAX calls. Then when I try to save an updated model, it saves everything again holding the old references to the photos I have just deleted.

How can I update my model ( remove the deleted photos from [ `model.Realty.Photos` ] )  so that it reflects the current state of my Edit view?

Note: now it's working because I'm using the `Session` object to store the Ids of deleted photos, but it's not the way I think it should be. There must be a beautiful solution to this that just doesn't come to my mind...

A beautiful solution would be: after a success deletion, the Ajax call should return the deleted photo Id so that I could remove it from [ `model.Realty.Photos` ]. Then, when I tried to save an edited Realty, it would reflect the changes correctly.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are inside a view and are sending an AJAX request from the client using javascript. What view model are you talking about? The view model has long gone. Do you need to update some DOM elements such as input fields or something in the AJAX success callback?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I'm working with the `RealtyViewModel` in the parent and partial views... exactly: I need to change the `model.Realty.Photos` after a success callback...

Comment: the success callback is a **javascript function**. Javascript runs on the client. What model are you talking about?

Comment: That's my doubt... maybe I'm going the wrong way here. I need to remove the photo I just deleted from this property: `model.Realty.Photos` after executing the Ajax action method on the controller. The problem is that I have no access to this model property when an Ajax call is made. Note that `Realty.Photos` is part of the `RealtyViewModel` I'm using in both views.

Comment: of course that you don't have access to it. You don't have access to any server side object from your javascript. Server side objects such as models run on the server. Once you render the HTML to the client there is HTML and javascript (and probably a bit of a CSS). So I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. You want to remove some DOM element?

Comment: So: is there any other way of accomplishing this? The `Session` variable approach I mention in the question is working for now.

Comment: Sorry, I am completely confused about what you are trying to achieve. Hopefully someone else will understand and be able to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7913/discussion-between-leniel-macaferi-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a [discussion on chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7913/discussion-between-leniel-macaferi-and-darin-dimitrov) it seems that you have hidden fields in your DOM that you need to remove:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Realty.Photos.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(
        m => m.Realty.Photos[i], 
        new { data_photoid = Model.Realty.Photos[i] }
    )
}
```

Now you could have your controller action return the id of the photo that has to be deleted using JSON for example instead of an empty result:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeletePhoto(string realtyId, string photoId)
{
    ... 
    return Json(new { photoId = photoId });
}
```

and on the client:

```
function deletePhotoFromPage(result) { 
    ...
    $(':hidden[data-photoid="' + result.photoId + '"]').remove(); 
}
```

and also you should use the `OnSuccess` option instead of `OnComplete` in your Ajax link options:

```
OnSuccess = "deletePhotoFromPage"
```

instead of:

```
OnComplete = string.Format("deletePhotoFromPage('{0}')", Model.Photos[i].Id),
```

`OnComplete` could be invoked even in case of error.

Comment: it's still not working. I don't know why. The DOM element continues on the page... :( strange enough is that when I'm hitting the Save button inside the Edit.cshtml view, I'm getting `realtyViewModel.Realty.Photos = null` inside the Edit action method on the controller. It should return something since I'm including the hidden fields on the page. Shouldn't this be the case?

Comment: I think the model binder doesn't like the hidden inputs that are being generated in the code...

Comment: It started working when I moved it to the OnComplete instead of the OnSuccess... I was using OnSuccess according to your advice. why is this this way? Now the DOM elements are being removed. Maybe because OnSuccess is to early and jQuery can't find the elements on the page? There is a problem: when I hit save the postback still contains the photos I have just deleted (removed the hidden fields) from the DOM...

Comment: @LenielMacaferi, `OnSuccess` is called after `OnComplete`. The code should work. What is the value of the photoId argument inside your `deletePhotoFromPage` function? Also notice the syntax: `OnSuccess = "deletePhotoFromPage"`. And also inside your controller action `return Json(new { photoId = photoId });`. And inside the `deletePhotoFromPage` you could use `result.photoId`. Inspect with FireBug the exact response sent from the server and the value of `result.photoId`. As far as your second problem is concerned, you will have to show your models and POST action.

Comment: Also take a look at the wire format that the default model binder uses for binding collections: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx. If you cannot solve the issue, you could send me by email a sample narrowed down version of your project that exhibits the issue and I would be happy to take a look and help you.

Comment: @Darin... I've read Scott Hanselman post but couldn't find a relatiion with this problem. My code right now is like what you showed in your answer. I'll edit the question to show the model and the Edit action method.

Comment: heheh should but isn't... something is missing yet!

Comment: Kept it on the OnSuccess callback and it is removing the input hidden now, but then the Model binder fails. This is frustrating... I'm getting null for the `model.Realty.Photos` property.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi, I've noticed that your hidden fields are named like `name="Realty.Photos[0]"`. Then you say that you are trying to bind this to a `model.Realty.Photos` property in your POST action. But according to your model this `Photos` property is a `Collection<File>`. So you are basically trying to bind the value of  your hidden field (which is like `file-1234`) to a complex `File` object which obviously doesn't make any sense. For example if you wanted to bind the ids you should use `m => m.Realty.Photos[i].Id` when generating your hidden field so `name="Realty.Photos[0].Id"`.

Comment: dear @Darin... before you wrote the above comment I went and changed the name of that collection to Files instead of Photos. I thought that could be the problem too. I'm testing this change right now. The thing is that I have simple strings inside `m => m.Realty.Photos`. So, when I do `m => m.Realty.Photos[i]` it's writing the string content itself. I don't have properties inside each index.

Comment: @Darin... you misunderstood this:  `model.Realty.Photos` is the property I'm trying to get the values back inside the Edit action method. `model.Photos` is related to the `RealtyViewModel` I'm passing to the view. They're different.

Comment: Also... my form declaration start with: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Realty", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` I use this same form to upload new photos...

Comment: @LenielMacaferi, I misunderstand because you are not showing your code and I am throwing blind guesses here. After the gazillions of comments I have no more idea how your code looks right now. How your markup looks like. To what model you are trying to bind it on the server and so on.